# Solve for L in $f(x) - f(y) - \nabla f(y)^\top (x-y) \leq \frac{L}{2} (x-y)^\top (x-y)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have that

$$
f(x) - f(y) - \nabla f(y)^\top (x-y) \leq \frac{L}{2} (x-y)^\top (x-y)
$$

And $$f(x)= \frac{1}{2}(Mx-b)^\top(Mx-b)$$
I begin by expanding $f(x)$ and $f(y)$, computing $\nabla f(y)(x-y)$, so that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\Big[x^\top M^\top M x - b^\top Mx - b^\top Mx + b^\top b - \big(y^\top M^\top M y - b^\top My - b^\top My + b^\top b\big) \Big] - (M^\top M y - M^\top b)^\top (x-y) &\leq \frac{L}{2} (x-y)^\top (x-y)\\
\frac{1}{2}\Big[x^\top M^\top M x - b^\top Mx - b^\top Mx + b^\top b - \big(y^\top M^\top M y - b^\top My - b^\top My + b^\top b\big) \Big] - \big(y^\top M^\top M x - y^\top M^\top M y - b^\top Mx + b^\top My \big) & \leq \frac{L}{2} (x-y)^\top (x-y)\\
\frac{1}{2}\Big[x^\top M^\top M x - 2b^\top Mx - y^\top M^\top M y + 2b^\top My - 2y^\top M^\top M x + 2y^\top M^\top M y+ 2b^\top Mx - 2 b^\top My \Big] &\leq \frac{1}{2}(x-y)^\top (x-y) \\
\frac{1}{2}\Big[ x^\top M^\top M x - 2y^\top M^\top M x+ y^\top M^\top M y\Big] &\leq \frac{L}{2} (x-y)^\top (x-y)\\
\frac{1}{2} (x-y)^\top M^\top M (x-y) &\leq \frac{L}{2} (x-y)^\top (x-y)
\end{align}

However, I'd like $L$ to be in terms of $M$ and $b$. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Edit: I added more of my derivation for clarity.

Comment: Your derivative is false. We have $\nabla f(x) = M^T(Mx-b)$.

Comment: That's what I have. My derivative is w.r.t to $y$. I have $M^\top M y - M^\top b = M^\top (My - b)$

Comment: OK, I did not read correctly. Does everything hold for *all* $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Yes, this is the definition of f(x) being L-smooth

Comment: Then you have $z^TM^TMz\le Lz^Tz$ for all $z$. In one dimension it reads $m^2z^2\le Lz^2$, so $L\ge m^2$. How would you *solve* that for $L$? It's an inequality. There is nothing to solve. Or do you just want a lower bound for $L$ as in the one-dimensional case, where $L\ge m^2$?

Comment: Exactly, I would like a lower bound for $L$.

Comment: Its the largest eigenvalue of $M^TM$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A$ is a symmetric matrix, then $\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$ equals the largest eigenvalue of $A$ (see, e.g., [Min-Max Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem)). Hence, since
$$
L\ge\frac{x^TM^TMx}{x^Tx}
$$
is supposed to hold for all $x$, the smallest valid value for $L$ is the largest eigenvalue of $M^TM$ (which is at the same time $\|M\|^2$ or the square of the largest singular value of $M$).

Comment: can you please elaborate on that parenthesis? How do find that $\lambda_{max}=||M||^2$?

Comment: @mil00 It's just the definition of $\|M\|$: $\max_{x\neq 0}\frac{x^TM^TMx}{x^Tx} = \max_{x\neq 0}\frac{(Mx)^TMx}{x^Tx} = \max_{x\neq 0}\frac{\|Mx\|^2}{\|x\|^2} = \|M\|^2$.